# Movable object wont rotate in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am using following code to rotate an object and its set to movable in editor.

```
void URotateMe::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    FRotator rot = Owner->GetTransform().Rotator();

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("rotation before : %s"), *rot.ToString());

    Owner->GetTransform().SetRotation(FQuat(rot.Add(0, 20, 0)));

    rot = Owner->GetTransform().Rotator();

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("rotation after : %s"), *rot.ToString());
}
```

Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong, since I am new to Unreal Engine.

Comment: Please include more detail, and context. Including what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check that in your BeginPlay() method, you have

```
AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
```

Otherwise UE won't recognize the `Owner` pointer in 
`FRotator rot = Owner->GetTransform().Rotator();`

Also, for `Owner->GetTransform().SetRotation(FQuat(rot.Add(0, 20, 0)));` I suggest staying away from `FQuat` as a beginner since Quaternion references can be a little weird. Try using the `SetActorRotation()` method (which by the way has multiple signatures, including FQuat() and Frotator()) so you can do something like this instead:

```
Owner->GetTransform().SetActorRotation(FRotator(0.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f));   // notice I am using SetActorRotation(), NOT SetRotation()
```

Or even better, this is what your code should look like in your **BeginPlay()**:

```
AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
FRotator CurrentRotation = FRotator(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
Owner->SetActorRotation(CurrentRotation);
```

and then your **TickComponent()**:

```
CurrentRotation += FRotator(0.0, 20.0f, 0.0f)  
Owner->SetActorRotation(CurrentRotation);      // rotate the Actor by 20 degrees on its y-axis every single frame
```